# Best road map to start learning ASP.NET MVC to expert level

Tags: asp.net-mvc

With so much to learn and so frequent updates in MS ASP.NET MVC framework, I find it little challenging to grab it quickly and extend the learning upto expert level efficiently.

I need advise upon how to start with (Is there any best tutorial ) and how can I reach expert level ( any **roadmap** so that we can be there)?

Any best available trainings (I can refer online)
or any guide so that I can miss unwanted areas and focus only on what is latest and good to use.

I am open for hardwork, but I need a right direction to follow up so that I don't get hindered chosing/referring wrong areas in learning process.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The good thing about the MVC framework in .Net is that its fundamentals don't change and have not changed ever since its first version was released. What you'll notice is that certain things have been made easier to do in the later versions.

My suggestion is to ignore the versions for the time being and focus on learning the MVC pattern. It may take writing a couple of short examples for you to become comfortable with the MVC pattern. Try to spend enough time on Routes and defining routes because they are really important part of any MVC framework.

The Razor ViewEngine and its syntax (introduced in MVC 3) is great for writing views. I definitely recommend to learn about Razor.

Once you get that then you should try to familiarize yourself with the .Net Framework as you'll end up using its classes  alot.

There are some nice tutorials on the [Tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/asp-net-from-scratch/) website that go through fundamentals of Asp.net MVC framework.

**What next?**

The step after the basics is to familiarize yourself with different development models such as:

- Test Driven Development (TDD)
- Domain Driven Development (DDD)
- Behavior Driven Development (BDD)

All are good models. You may choose one depending on which you personally find suitable for your project.

Inversion of Control (IoC) is a technique you'll see used a lot in Asp.Net MVC examples and it's a good practice to learn about.

You may also find ORM such as NHibernate and the Entity Frameworks(EF) interesting to use. ORM itself is a big topic and you will have to learn a lot once you dive into them. I've used both 
the EF and NHibernate. I preferred NHibernate because it's opensource and at the time had a larger user community.

Anyway, I hope this overview gives you some ideas about where to start.

Answer (score 2):

This roadmap can be useful in this case

[image: image1]

Follow the link below to see the details:

https://github.com/MoienTajik/AspNetCore-Developer-Roadmap

Answer (score 0):

NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you full control over markup for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET MVC includes many features that enable fast, TDD-friendly development for creating sophisticated applications that use the latest web standards. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/index.htm is one of the coolest tutorial link I think